# Limit no of mapper in MultipleOutput without reducer in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Hi i have an application that reads records from HBase and writes into text files HBase table has 200 regions.
I am using MultipleOutputs in the mapper class to write into multiple files and i am making file name from the incoming records .

I am making 40 unique file names .
I am able to get records properly but my problem is that when mapreduce finishes it creates 40 files and also 2k extra files with proper name but appended 
with m-000 and so on.

This is because i have 200 regions and MultipleOutputs creates files for each mapper so 200 mapper and for each mapper there are 40 unique files so that is why it creates 40*200 files .

I don't know how to avoid this situation without custom partitioner .

Is there any way to force write records into belonging files only not to split into multiple files.

I have used custom partitioner class and its working fine but i don't want to use that as i am just reading from HBase and not doing reducer operation.Also if any extra file name i have to create then i have to change my code also .

Here is my mapper code

```
   public class DefaultMapper extends TableMapper<NullWritable, Text> {
        private Text text = new Text();
        MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text> multipleOutputs;
        String strName = "";

        @Override()
        public void setup(Context context) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException {
            multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text>(context);
        }
String FILE_NAME = new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FILE_NAME)));

        multipleOutputs.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(text.toString()),FILE_NAME);
        //context.write(NullWritable.get(), text);
    }
```

No reducer class

This is how my output looks like ideally only one `Japan.BUS.gz` file should be created.Other files are very small files also

```
Japan.BUS-m-00193.gz
Japan.BUS-m-00194.gz
Japan.BUS-m-00195.gz
Japan.BUS-m-00196.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same situation and made a solution for it also.

```
MultipleOutputs multipleOutputs = null;

String keyToFind = new String();

    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        this.multipleOutputs_normal = new MultipleOutputs<KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>(context);
    }

public void map(NullWritable key , Text values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{

   String valToFindInCol[] = values.toString.split(",");/** Lets say comma seperated **/

    if (keyToFind .equals(valToFindInCol[2].toString())|| keyToFind == null) /** Say you need to match 2 position element **/
    {
        this.multipleOutputs.write(NullWritable.get(),<valToWrite>, valToFindInCol[2]);
    } 
    else 
    {
        this.multipleOutputs.close();
        this.multipleOutputs = null;
        this.multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>(context);

        this.multipleOutputs.write(NullWritable.get(),<valToWrite>, valToFindInCol[2]);

    }

    keyToFind=valToFindInCol[2];
}
```

Comment: i did not get your solution .why this problem occurs?i am closing it correctly then why this problem will come

Comment: For one partition it is creating 198 files ..i have 200 number of mapper so may be one file per mapper

Comment: I had filenames in key and the line as values, so whenever we were getting new filename, i was closing the old file and creating a new output file specifying the name. How is your records( for a definite key) scattered, in multiple or single file ?

Comment: I have nullWritable key and one column from the record is my file name.I will have 40 unique file names.

Comment: please find my updated answer and let me know if it is of any help.

Comment: Thanks i will implement that will let you know .But if i have several files then i have to write so many if else in the map logic ?To avoid this only i thought to switch from custom partitioner to MultipleOutput ..Any way i am give try this also

Comment: If your data is already sorted, I mean it maintains a certain order( like AA keys will come , then only AB series key will come),then only, the piece of code I have shared will be of importance, else if your data is scattered, then we might need another approach.(like you may need to pre-process the data to the above format).If the key order is maintained , then I don't think you need to write any more code.

Comment: Then I am afraid, you might need to write another m/r to make it in the specified format.( If you have the option of doing it ).